# What is this tool called in the toolbox of visual studio?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, toolbox

I'm talking about the White boxes with red colored border that you store labels and textboxes.  I have found a similar tool I think, it's called the TableLayoutPanel.  But I can't insert more than 1 stuff in each column (or boxes).

[image]

Comment: This is most likely a GridLayout

Comment: Insert a panel control or usercontrol first into each cell with the dock property set to fill, then you can add other controls on top of those.

Comment: @JaredPar, 300k points? That's god level @_@ Sir. Probably just BackColor changed Panels connected with each other.

Comment: @chris_techno25 or a sign of someone who spends too much time on their laptop :)

Comment: Its a grid layout with red gridlines, there are panels on the grid and those panels have the other controls on them.

Comment: @LarsTech - Works like a charm.  Thanks!  Also, how do you change the border color to Red or whatever?  It's is black by default and I can't find anywhere to change

Comment: @JaredPar, I don't care what you say, you answer a question and what? You only get 15 points? I spend a lot of time on my computer reading and learning new stuff about robotics, software and automation, and I can't even answer 99.99% of the questions. I don't know how you did it, but 300+ points is beyond human.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are looking at the TableLayoutPanel control, which is designed to allow only a single control in a cell.  So to get multiple controls into a single cell would require a UserControl or a container control, like a Panel, and set the dock style to Fill.

One way to get the red borders is to set all of the child UserControl or Panel control's Margin properties to zero, set the TableLayoutPanel's `CellBorderStyle = Single`, and then use the TableLayoutPanel's paint event to just draw the background:

```
void tlp_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Red);
}
```